# video as texture in Qt3D 2.0

Tags: qt, video, textures, qt3d

I am using Qt 5.5.0 and Qt3D 2.0.
I want to display video as texture.
I can display and rotate only one image.
How can I add a video instead of an image?

Comment: Please, do not use bold font for your whole question

Comment: Did you find anything? In 5.6 it's now possible to use a QtQuick item as a texture in Canvas3D, but no mention of using them with Qt3D. https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtcanvas3d-canvas3d-quickitemtexture-example.html